# How to create subplotted bar charts from a dictionary within a dictionary

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to make subplots which are bar charts of the following dictionary: `dict1 = {44: {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 3, 4: 6}, 45:{0: 1, 1: 4, 2: 2, 3: 0, 4: 0}}`

```
This was my (not correct) code:
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,1)
for nr in dict1: 
        ax[list(dict1.keys()).index(nr),1].plot(list(dict1[nr].keys()), list(dict1[nr].values()), kind='bar')
        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.show
```

Can you help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `for nr in dict1.keys():`

Answer (score 0):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,1)
for nr in dict1.keys():   
    ax[list(dict1.keys()).index(nr)].bar(
        list(dict1[nr].keys()),
        list(dict1[nr].values())
    )
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: please add an explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot wrong with the code in the question. Two options:

#### Matplotlib style plotting

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dict1 = {44: {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 3, 4: 6}, 45:{0: 1, 1: 4, 2: 2, 3: 0, 4: 0}}

fig, axs = plt.subplots(len(dict1.keys()))
for (k, d), ax in zip(dict1.items(), axs):
    ax.bar(*zip(*d.items()))
    ax.set_title(k)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### Pandas style plotting

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dict1 = {44: {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 3, 4: 6}, 45:{0: 1, 1: 4, 2: 2, 3: 0, 4: 0}}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)

df.plot.bar(subplots=True)
    
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]